# Unexpected behavior from variable reference in a closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I ran into an issue when I expect a member in a returned object to have the correct value of a variable defined in the parent scope. However, the value of this member never changes and I had to make a getter method to retrieve the correct value. For a trivial example, below is a subset of an Adjacency Matrix representation of a graph:

```
function AdjacencyMatrix() {
    // Here is the set of Vertices
    var V = [1, 2, 3];

    // Here's some functionality that will remove a vertex at some point,
    // right now we're just concerned with updating what V is equal to
    function removeVertex(v) {
        V.push(4);
        V = [];
        console.log(V);
    }

    // A "getter" method for the list of vertices
    function getVertices() {
      return V;   
    }

    // Ran when the Adjacency Matrix is initialized
    console.log(V);

    return Object.freeze({
        // Member that holds a reference to V
        vertices: V,

        // Methods that will be used later
        removeVertex: removeVertex,
        getVertices: getVertices
    });
}

// Initially logs [1, 2, 3], which is expected
var M = AdjacencyMatrix();

// Logs [], which is expected
M.removeVertex();

// Logs [1, 2, 3, 4], which is unexpected.
// Instead, it should log []
console.log(M.vertices);

// Logs [], which is expected
console.log(M.getVertices());
```

Shouldn't the `vertices` member in the returned object always maintain a reference to what the variable `V` points to? Instead, in this example, accessing the `vertices` member on `M` maintains a reference to the array initially assigned to the variable `V` and ignores any reassignment of variable `V`.

Or, when assigning the `vertices` member to `V`, does it hold a reference to the value of `V` instead of  whatever value the variable has?

Sorry if the wording of this problem is difficult to understand, I tried my best to state my expectations and results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M.vertices` does not involve a closure.

In an object literal, the right hand side of each key/value pair is *evaluated*, and the result of that evaluation is what is assigned to each the object's properties.

When this executes:

```
return Object.freeze({
    // Member that holds a reference to V
    vertices: V,

    // Methods that will be used later
    removeVertex: removeVertex,
    getVertices: getVertices
});
```

`V` is evaluated to the array that `V` is referencing at that moment. So the produced object references that array, but it has no connection to `V`.

---

To get the behavior you are describing (if that is what you indeed want). You could define a getter and setter for `vertices` that do use a closure:

```
var o = {
    // Methods that will be used later
    removeVertex: removeVertex,
    getVertices: getVertices
}

Object.defineProperty(o, 'vertices', {
    get: function () { return V; },
    set: function (val) { V = val; } // or you can omit the setter
                                     // to make the property readonly
}); 

return Object.freeze(o);
```

Comment: I love this explanation! I do have one question though, why does the value of `M.vertices` get updated to `[1, 2, 3, 4]` instead of staying at `[1, 2, 3]`? In the `removeVertex` method, I'm pushing the value 4 onto `M` and this change is reflected when I access `M.vertices`.

Comment: Because you're still holding a reference, so you can mutate the referred object and observe mutations.

Comment: @JoshBlack It's what zerkms said. Evaluating the expression `V` does not create a brand new array. It produces a reference to the array that `V` is referencing at that time. If that array is modified afterward, then it will be reflected when you access it via `M.vertices`.

Answer (score 2):

`vertices: V,` means:

put a reference to what `V` refers to to the `vertices` property.

That's it - it's not a closure, it's just an assignment.

So as soon as you reassign `V` to refer to something else - the `vertices` attribute does not reflect that, since it stores an original reference.

Answer (score 0):

Vertices holds the value of V that was originally assigned to it. If you come from an object oriented language background like C#, this is equivalent to "pass by value" (i.e only the value gets passed and not the reference).

Comment: Why is it not true ? Although is not technically "pass by value", conceptually it is easier to understand it this way. The 'value' of V is assigned to Vertices and not its reference.

Comment: It's not "pass by value" in any way. Like at all. It has a special name "call by sharing". "The 'value' of V is assigned to Vertices and not its reference." --- this is simply wrong, since it's exactly the opposite: it's the reference that is assigned.

Comment: I still don't get it. If it is the reference that is assigned to Vertices, then why doesn't it get updated when V changes ?

Comment: Does M.removeVertex(); not mutate it ?

Comment: If it was mutated by M.removeVertex(); then console.log(M.vertices); should have logged [] instead of [1,2,3,4]

Comment: No, it should not. It first mutated it with `.push(4)`. Then it created a separate object. `V = [];` statement creates another object, while the old one is not dropped, since the other variables hold a reference to it.

Comment: Thanks! It is clear now and the parallel in C# for this behaviour is "pass reference type by value".

Comment: "pass reference type by value" --- it's called "call by sharing" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing